# add eCheck.Net to CIM

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

How can I add **eCheck** account to **CIM** for recurrent billing?

I cannot use **ARB**, because every month payments are different values. And my current web app already use **CIM**.

Is any way to integrate **eCheck** with **CIM**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorize.Net CIM supports storing and using both credit cards and checks for payments.  You can review the details using the API Reference located at http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#manage-customer-profiles-create-customer-payment-profile